# Ubuntu 16.04 boots to install prompt

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, usb

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. After i rebooted it it opens to the installation prompt instead of booting normally. It isn't until after quitting that it boots normal. Any advice or possible fix?

Comment: I used a bootable usb

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty sure that your usb drive is still connected to your laptop or else it will never show you installation prompt without an installation drive connected to the device.
if you have an issue with grub you can just fix it with grub boot loader.

Comment: I took out the usb and it boots straight to windows

Comment: i guess your question is that you can't boot to ubuntu after installation, right! but it boots normally to windows?, if it's the case tell us if you got any errors during the installation of grub, and if not what is your problem precisely?